# Java Concurrency Issues concerning Listeners

Tags: java, vector, concurrency, concurrentmodification

What is the best, or the common solution to concurrency concerning Java? I see a lot of solutions on this and other websites, but none of them work for my problem.

My problem is as follows: I have a `vector` of a `class` I wrote myself. (If this helps solving it I can just as easily make it an `ArrayList` or something like that)
Now, on a very regular basis (up to thousands of times per second) I read all elements in this `vector` and manipulate them in some way. At the same time I add and remove elements bases on events in my `MouseListener` and my `KeyListener` (which is essential to the program). This of course gives me quite a few problems. I don't want to read the `vector` while adding or removing elements, because this would throw a `java.util.ConcurrentModificationException`. However, I can't really use a temporary `vector` to store these events because that would create the problem of clearing this `vector` while adding things to it. How do you get out of this mess?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can wrap your Vector of items with a thread safe wrapper using java.util.Collections. There is a specific method for List i.e. synchronizedList but not for Vector. This only solves part of the problem by synchronizing all the public method calls, add() and remove() etc.

```
private Collection<Thing> things =
         Collections.synchronizedCollection(new Vector<Thing>());
```

(or for a List)

```
private Collection<Thing> listeners =
       Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<Thing>());
```

You also need to protect your iteration... There are two ways to do this, either lock the collection whilst you iterate...

```
synchronized (things) {
    for (Thing thing : things) {

    }
}
```

or take a copy and iterate over that...

```
for (Thing thing : things.toArray(new MouseListener[]{})) {

}
```

Comment: You misunderstood me, this does not concern a vector of listeners. It's about `add` and `remove` called by listeners. Anyhow, this provided some useful info so I'll see if it helps. Downvote was not me by the way :P

Comment: Thanks, updated my answer... principles are still exactly the same, I do a lot of GUI stuff, so wrongly assumed.

Comment: Also, if you could provide the answer for just a list that would be appreciated (though I think I'll be able to do it myself, so if not: no problem). I used the vector to fix some issue I do not have anymore anyways.

Comment: Add List example to question, everything else is same after the initial construction...

Comment: Oh lol, I didn't realise hardly anything would change :P Thx!

Comment: `Vector` already has all its operations synchronised, making a synchronised collection of it is pointless.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use a [`CopyOnWriteArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html). This is safe to use in multithreaded and concurrent programming environments.

When iterating over a `CopyOnWriteArrayList` you will not get `ConcurrentModificationException`s as any changes create a new array internally and do not affect the one being iterated over. It was pretty much designed to host a list of listeners.

This has the benefit of not needing any synchronisation when iterating, and has very short locked segments, iteration will never block!